# Can I copy the code snipptes created in Texmaker to another computer?

Tags: texmaker, code-snippets

I'm trying to locate the folder where the code snippets I've created in Texmaker are stored. The reason is that I want to copy them to another computer(I don't want to create each single snippet again). Is there a way to copy these snippets and transfer them either from within Texmaker or externally finding the folder and copy that, or is it impossible? I'm sitting on a Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about the User Tags? Looks like they're stored in the settings file, you can save a copy of that by doing Options --> Settings file --> Save a copy of the settings file. To use such a file in Texmaker, do Options --> Settings file --> Replace the settings file by a new one.

Comment: Yes I think that will solve it! Takk skal du ha:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User tags appear to be stored in the main settings file. You can get a copy of that file by doing *Options --> Settings file --> Save a copy of the settings file*. (If you open this file in a text editor you'll find `User\Tag1=...` etc. near the bottom of the file.)

In the same menu, *Options --> Settings*, there is an entry called *Replace the settings file by a new one*. I haven't tried this, but presumably you should be able to copy the saved settings file from one computer to the other, and use that menu entry to replace the original settings file.

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, this is what I'm looking for, but should I save this copy with a particular extension? e.g. .tex/txt/... etc.?

Comment: @Thomas `.ini` I believe.